# Ola Hallengren IntegrityCheck Excludes TempDB

Tags: ola-hallengren

According to [SQL Server Maintenance Solution - SQL Server Integrity Check](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html), the `SYSTEM_DATABASES` value includes only master, msdb, and model.

Why is TempDB excluded, when it too can have hardware issues causing page corruptions?

Interestingly enough, [DBCC CheckDB FAQ: Check for Corruption in SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/dbcc-checkdb-faq/) by Kendra Little talks about the need to check TempDB but points to the Ola Hallengren script, which does not appear to be checking TempDB by default.

Answer (score 4):

*<sub>Answer based on a comment left by [Randi Vertongen](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/144393/randi-vertongen):</sub>*

Ola mentioned a long time ago (+5 years) [on SQL Server Central](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1606016-2799-1.aspx) that this is by default:

> This is by design. DatabaseIntegrityCheck is not doing checkdb on tempdb.

and a way around it by adding it explicitly.

> In the latest version you can do like this:
>
> ```
> EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseIntegrityCheck
>       @Databases = 'SYSTEM_DATABASES,tempdb',
>       @CheckCommands = 'CHECKDB'
> ```

He goes on to say:

> When I developed the scripts I was looking at how Microsoft was doing in the Maintenance Plans. They are not doing checkdb for tempdb, so I did also not do that. Some time ago I added support for checking of tempdb, but not as the default. You need to specify tempdb explicitly.

Not entirely sure if this is still the case.

Answer (score 2):

Ola's scripts do not do checkdb on tempdb as seen in the [code base](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/blob/master/DatabaseIntegrityCheck.sql#L433). Tempdb is a scratch db and gets recreated when sql server reboots.

Brent has a point in doing checkdb on tempdb. You can file an [issue on github](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues) to get it into future release.